# RAW 12 bits per pixel data format

Tags: image, image-processing

I was analyzing a 12 bit per pixel, GRBG, Little Endian, 1920x1280 resolution raw image but I am confused how data or RGB pixels are stored. Image size is 4915200 bytes, when calculated 4915200/(1920x1280) = 2. That means each pixel takes 2 bytes and 4 bits in 2bytes are used for padding. I tried to edit image with Hex editor but I have no idea how pixels are stored in image. Please do share if you have any idea.

[Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WjAkdDr8_Ty1M-Vrbq7uCiISCnGSQQdH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe share the image - probably with Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: If you know how to view the image in Irfanview, you surely could include a screen-grab showing a) how the image is supposed to look and b) what settings/description you gave Irfanview of the data? If you wan folks to help you - make it easy for them! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That means each pixel takes 2 bytes and 4 bits in 2bytes are used for padding

Well, sort of. It means each *sample* is stored in two consecutive bytes, with 4 bits of padding. But in raw images, samples usually aren't pixels, not exactly. Raw images have not been demosaiced yet, they are raw after all. For GRGB, the Bayer pattern looks like this:

[image: bayer GRGB]

What's in the file, is a 1920x1280 grid of 12+4 bit samples, arranged in the same order as pixels would have been, but each sample has only one channel, namely the one that corresponds to its position in the Bayer pattern.

Additionally, the color space is probably linear, not Gamma-compressed. The color balance is unknown unless you reverse engineer it. A proper decoder would have a calibrated color matrix, but I don't have that.

I combined these two things and guessed a color balance to do a really basic decoding (with bad demosaicing, just to demonstrate that the above information is probably accurate):

[image: decoded]

Using this C# code:

```
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1920, 1280);        
    for (int y = 0; y < 1280; y += 2)
    {
        int i = y * 1920 * 2;
        for (int x = 0; x < 1920; x += 2)
        {
            const int stride = 1920 * 2;
            int d0 = data[i] + (data[i + 1] << 8);
            int d1 = data[i + 2] + (data[i + 3] << 8);
            int d2 = data[i + stride] + (data[i + stride + 1] << 8);
            int d3 = data[i + stride + 2] + (data[i + stride + 3] << 8);
            i += 4;
            int r = Math.Min((int)(Math.Sqrt(d1) * 4.5), 255);
            int b = Math.Min((int)(Math.Sqrt(d2) * 9), 255);
            int g0 = Math.Min((int)(Math.Sqrt(d0) * 5), 255);
            int g3 = Math.Min((int)(Math.Sqrt(d3) * 5), 255);
            int g1 = Math.Min((int)(Math.Sqrt((d0 + d3) * 0.5) * 5), 255);
            bm.SetPixel(x, y,         Color.FromArgb(r, g0, b));
            bm.SetPixel(x + 1, y,     Color.FromArgb(r, g1, b));
            bm.SetPixel(x, y + 1,     Color.FromArgb(r, g1, b));
            bm.SetPixel(x + 1, y + 1, Color.FromArgb(r, g3, b));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @harold. I know how to see what is the content of image. I used [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/64bit.htm) to see the demosaiced image. But my question is how pixels are stored or the pattern (GRBG) of data. I tried to analyze your code but I am confused. let say I want to create a 12bpp, 2x2 raw image with first color as red and remaining white. Then the hex data will be | 0F 00 | FF FF | FF FF | FF FF |. But when I put this data in Irfanview (RAW image viewer) image is not the one as expected.

Comment: @saivamsi the scenario that you proposed makes no sense to me, the top left sample is green by definition. You cannot independently choose colors per pixel as if the image was a normal bitmap. GRBG does not refer to the interpretation of the hex digits within a sample, it refers to the pattern of the samples.

Comment: I got it. I was thinking RGB colors are combined stored in 12bits. I was confused at bits per pixel, it was actually bits per color. Thank you @harold the explanation and code.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your image into a Numpy array and reshape correctly like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Load image and reshape
img = np.fromfile('Image_12bpp_grbg_LittleEndian_1920x1280.raw',dtype=np.uint16).reshape((1280,1920))

print(img.shape)
(1280, 1920)
```

Then you can demosaic and scale to get a 16-bit PNG. Note that I don't know your calibration coefficients so I guessed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Demosaicing Bayer Raw image
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823014/2836621

import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'Image_12bpp_grbg_LittleEndian_1920x1280.raw'

# Set width and height
w, h = 1920, 1280

# Read mosaiced image as GRGRGR...
#                        BGBGBG...
bayer = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((h,w))

# Extract g0, g1, b, r from mosaic
g0 = bayer[0::2, 0::2]      # every second pixel down and across starting at 0,0
g1 = bayer[1::2, 1::2]      # every second pixel down and across starting at 1,1
r  = bayer[0::2, 1::2]      # every second pixel down and across starting at 0,1
b  = bayer[1::2, 0::2]      # every second pixel down and across starting at 1,0

# Apply (guessed) color matrix for 16-bit PNG
R = np.sqrt(r) * 1200
B = np.sqrt(b) * 2300
G = np.sqrt((g0+g1)/2) * 1300    # very crude

# Stack into 3 channel
BGR16 = np.dstack((B,G,R)).astype(np.uint16)

# Save result as 16-bit PNG
cv2.imwrite('result.png', BGR16)
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, raw, image processing, Bayer, de-Bayer, mosaic, demosaic, de-mosaic, GBRG, 12-bit.